# Showing a set has Jordan content

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

The question is:

> Let $a<b$ and $f\colon [a,b]\rightarrow[0,\infty)$ be continuous. Let $D = \{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2\mid x\in[a,b],\: y\in[0,f(x)]\}$. Show that D has content and $$ \mu(D) = \int_{a}^bf(x)\,dx. $$
>
> Here, $\mu(D)$ is the Jordan content of $D$.

If I can show $D$ has content, the rest is easy since
$$\mu(D) = \int_{D}1 = \int_{a}^{b}\int_{0}^{f(x)}1\,dydx = \int_{a}^{b}f(x)\,dx$$

However, I am having trouble showing $D$ has content. I know of two ways to show a set has Jordan content: either show $\mu(\partial(D)) = 0$, where $\partial(D)$ is the boundary of $D$, or show that $1$ is Riemann integrable on $D$.

Using the boundary of $D$ seems more difficult. Is it enough to use the above computation of $\mu(D)$ to show that $1$ is Riemann integrable on $D$, since $f(x)$ is Riemann integrable on $[a,b]$ because $[a,b]$ is compact and $f$ is continuous? If this does not work (and I doubt it does), how could I show $D$ has content?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I.Every continuous real function on a bounded closed interval is Riemann integrable.Riemann and Lebesgue integration were intended to extend integration to broader classes of functions than classical integration. II.Since $f$ is continuous with domain $[a,b]$ it is bounded and uniformly continuous so it is easy to show that $\mu (\partial D)=0$ and that $\mu_*(D)=\mu^*(D).$ The continuity of $f$ implies that $\partial (D)=\cup_{i=1}^{i=4}A_i$ where $A_1=\{a\}\times \{[0,f(a)]\}$, $A_2=\{b\}\times [0,f(b)]\}$, $A_3=[a,b]\times \{0\}$, and $ A_4$ is the graph of $f$.Assume $a<b$. Given $e>0$ let $n$ be a positive integer such that $|x-y|<(b-a)/n\to |f(x)-f(y)|<e. $ We have $$A_4 \subset \bigcup_{j=0}^{j=n}[x_j,x_{j+1})\times [f(x_j)-e,f(x_j)+e)$$ $$\text {where } x_j=a+(b-a)j/n.$$ I will leave the rest to you.

Comment: How does the continuity of $f$ imply this? Is it possible to actually find the boundary of $D$?

Comment: standard epsilon-delta arguments and the definition of boundary suffice.

Comment: Does this use any theorem on the content of a union of sets? Would I have to show that each set in the union has content 0?

Comment: Yes. $\mu (a\cup b)\leq \mu (a)+\mu )b).$ The last formula  (last line) should have been union of course, not intersection.The sums of the contents of the terms in the RHS is 2e(n+1)/n which is at most  2e , and e can be arbitrarily small.

Comment: $A_4$ is the graph of $f$, so we could write $A_4=\{(x,f(x)):x\in[a,b]\}$. If $x\in[a,b]$ how can you guarantee that $x\in[\frac{j}{n},\frac{j+1}{n}]$? Similarly, how can you be sure that $f(x)\in[f(\frac{j}{n})-e,f(\frac{j}{n})+e]$?   Also, for $j=0$, $f(\frac{j}{n})=f(0)$, which is not defined if $0\notin [a,b]$.

Comment: sorry i didn't see that I was thinking of [a,b]=[0.1]. I made a change.

Comment: In general we have $\mu _*(a\cup b)\leq \mu_*(a)+\mu_*(b).$